# Center angular mat tabs content

Tags: angular, mat

Hello is it possible to center mat tabs content(label)?

```
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs>
  <mat-tab label="Personal" >
adada
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Others">

  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add wrapper with flex

```
  <mat-tab label="First"> 
    <div class="tab-content-center">
     My Content
    </div> 
  </mat-tab>
```

in css -

```
.tab-content-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```